# TypeError in Django REST framework Tutorial 1: Serialization

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I was wondering can someone help me and clarify this error for me.

I am doing the Django REST Framework Tutorial, and I got to the part when I am creating a Serializer class.

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False,
                                  max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'type': 'textarea'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                       default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                    default='friendly')

class Meta:
    model = Snippet
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')


def create(self, validated_attrs):
    """
    Create and return a new 'Snippet' instance, given the validated data.
    """
    return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_attrs)

def update(self, instance, validated_attrs):
    """
    Update and return an existing 'Snippet' instance, given the validated data.
    """
    instance.title = validated_attrs.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.code = validated_attrs.get('code', instance.code)
    instance.linenos = validated_attrs.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
    instance.language = validated_attrs.get('language', instance.language)
    instance.style = validated_attrs.get('style', instance.style)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Now mine problem is this, when I go in to the shell to serialize and when I want to import 
`from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer` the module throw this error:

```
>>> from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/petarp/Documents/Django_Rest_Framework/serialization_tutorial/tutorial/snippets/serializers.py", line 6, in <module>
    class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  File "/home/petarp/Documents/Django_Rest_Framework/serialization_tutorial/tutorial/snippets/serializers.py", line 10, in SnippetSerializer
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'type': 'textarea'})
  File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 468, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'style'
```

Can someone please clarify this error and help me overcome this.

Comment: Post your Snippet Model too please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `widget` attribute do define form field type:

```
code = serializers.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

You're probably using DRF v2.x.x, which doesn't support `style` argument in `Field` class

Comment: Your problem here is that you use the ModelSerializer (in the tutorial, they use the base serializers.Serializer). So the fields are not built in the same way and the 'style' keyword is not expected for the modelserializer :

The serializer.CharField does only support 'widget' as mariodev said.

Comment: Tank you for the heads up, when I used you code @mariodev I head another Traceback saying mine forms are not defined, so I used 'code = serializers.CharField(widget=widgets.Textarea()', and I sould read more carefully next time.